# Snells Law derivation from Plane Wave incidence

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, refraction, plane-wave

I am trying to derive snell's law from plane wave incidence by imposing the condition that the phase of the incident, reflected and transmitted wave at the point of incidence must be equal. Here's what I have

$$  \vec{k_i}.\vec{r} = \vec{k_r}.\vec{r} = \vec{k_t}.\vec{r} \hspace{18em}(1)$$

If $\vec{n}$ be a unit vector that points from medium 1 to medium 2 then

$$\vec{k} = \vec{k_{||}} + \vec{k_{\bot}}$$
$$\vec{k_{||}} = (\vec{k}.\vec{n})\vec{n} \hspace{3em}\vec{k_{\bot}} = (\vec{n}\times\vec{k})\times\vec{n}$$

Therefore equation (1) can be re-written as

$$k_{i\bot}r{\bot} + k_{i||}r_{||} = k_{r\bot}r{\bot} + k_{r||}r_{||} =k_{t\bot}r{\bot} + k_{t||}r_{||} \hspace{6em} (2)$$

Here's where I have hit a dead-end. I know that if I align my interface with 
$$\vec{r}.\vec{n} = 0$$

Then all the parallel components in (2) will disappear and I have snell's law but I was kind of curious if I can prove snell's law without making this assumption ?

Thanks